# Change MAC Address on Windows 7 - BootCamp (Macintosh)

Tags: windows-7, mac, macbook, mac-address

I need to change my MAC address on my Windows 7 partition on my Macbook Pro. I have tried changing the registry value on my Windows to spoof my address, but that didn't work. I have also tried to use SMAC, an application to spoof your MAC address, but that didn't work either. I have successfully changed my MAC address on my Macintosh partition through Terminal, but I can't get it spoofed on my Windows partition. If someone could help me on this issue, I would greatly appreciate it.

Kevin

Answer (score 2):

There are several choices of software to do this.

- http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/madmacs-mac-spoofer
- http://www.klcconsulting.net/smac/
- http://www.technitium.com/tmac/index.html

Some Ethernet drivers allow you to change it in the Adapter properties Advanced Tab.

[image]

Comment: Those methods do not work. As I have said, SMAC does not work, and the "Network Address" does not show up on my Wireless network card.

Answer (score 2):

My tool of choice for this would be Macshift

http://devices.natetrue.com/macshift/

Answer (score 1):

Probably your network card doesn’t support it. It’s a feature of the network card, not Windows. It would be helpful if you told us your network card make and model.